# Eclipse - identical version, but different plugin versions of "EMF Common" on different installations

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

A colleague and I are both using Eclipse 4.13 - specifically `2019-09 R, 20190917-1200`.

Both of us have `1.6.600.v20190907-0426` of the *Eclipse 4 Rich Client Platform* plugin installed.

This plugin contains the *EMF Common* plugin - but here the versions differ between `2.16.0.v20190625-1131` & `2.17.0.v20190920-0401`.

We actually have the same scenario with a third developer as well - with a third different version.

I'm confused as to how a consistent installation version can have inconsistent components? Ultimately these plugins are being exported into our RCP application.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Dependencies are defined by version ranges and installing a plug-in might update an existing plug-in as long as it is within the defined required version range. The second screenshot shows that a non-open source plug-in from Genuitec is installed that does load time weaving. As a result of this load time weaving, even the byte code that will be executed of some Eclipse plug-ins of the same version differ. To both of you, do not use an outdated Eclipse version and be careful which plug-ins you install.

Comment: Your RCP build should be using a target platform based on a specific repository (not the Running Platform) - so everyone is using the same thing.

Comment: For what _greg-449_ recommends, which I also think you should do, see https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTargetPlatform/article.html

Comment: Thanks both - as usual, StackOverflow solves the problem I actually had - not the question I posted :)